# Including a Handler Response inside a Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, handler

I am generating HTML in the Page Load method in more than 1 page.

All those generated HTML are the same across all pages.

I found that it's a pain to have the same codes in every page because once I need to change something, I need to change them in all pages.

Example:

I have a `div` in each of those page:

`<div id="Questions" runat="server"></div>`

In the `Page Load` method of each page, I generate the same HTML.

`Questions.InnerHTML  = "<span>...etc...</span>";`

So I decided to make a page that generates those contents, then load this page inside the div of the other pages, means, if I ever need to change, I only change this page.

I created a Handler, `Questions.ashx`. This handler generates that HTML and sends back a response.

Now to include it, I know I can use `JQUERY's` `.load()` function, but I would like to generate those HTML from server side.

What I've tried:

`Questions.InnerHTML = LoadControl("~/Handlers/Questions.ashx").ToString();`

But I received this error:

`Type 'Questions' does not inherit from 'System.Web.UI.UserControl'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"LoadControl" is for "User Controls", not HTTP Handlers..

You will probably be better off creating a User Control, which is an .ascx file.  This can contain HTML, ASPX controls and code behind, and can be referenced by any ASPX page.

More Info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to User Controls, my work will be much easier now.